# Checking if a list of arbitrary inequalities are satisfied

Tags: c++, constraints, graph-theory, inequality

I am writing some code in C++ and need to check whether or not a list of inequalities in two unknown variables are satisfied.

For example, one possible list could be P = Q, Q < S, P = S which should NOT be satisfied

Another example, P = Q, Q < S, R = P, S > R should be satisfied

I have thought long and hard how to do this but I cannot seem to find any method other then a long, tedious one which involves checking if every new inequality added satisfies all the previous ones.

Comment: Do you mean "can be satisfied" or "are satisfied by one particular set of values"? ... and where is the graph?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

Comment: @Yakk he's not actually that far off, orderings are not far from lattices which are a kind of graph. As for the C++ tag.... :P

Comment: @alecteal sure, but invoking polynomial equivalence means it should be on every algorithms question.  And you can express general Turning computation as a graph too.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an exercise in boolean logic than C++. If you know Python use it.

A faster way would be to construct an "ordering" (in the maths sense) one statement at a time. That is where you have a sequence, a b c suppose and a

Suppose now each thing in the sequence is a vector of things equal to each other. In the above example:

P=Q

Our ordering looks like:

[P,Q]

Next Q

So now as we have an ordering:

[P,Q],[S]

We know [P,Q]<[S]

So P=S is an obvious contradiction.

Comment: What about a list like this 

P = Q, Q < S, R < S.

Where would R be placed?

Comment: @user2454986 first [P,Q] then [P,Q],[S] then create the second list with [R],[S]. Keep going until contradiction.

Comment: Say I was working with a list of twenty inequalities with about 6 different unknown variables. It would get quite messy with having a number of lists. Maybe if there was always a contradiction it might not be so bad but all the inequalities could be correct too. I did think of a similar idea to the one you was mentioning when I was trying to figure out a way however I dismissed it for this reason.

Comment: You're reconstructing an ordering, you can merge orderings to an extent.... it's called a partition. @user2454986 get a god real analysis book

Answer (score -1):

First, remove all equalities `P = Q` by replacing all occurrences of `Q` with `P`.
This reduces `P = Q, Q < S, R = P, S > R` to `R < S, S > R`.

Second, build a directed graph with the variables as vertices and an edge from `P` to `Q` if your list constains `P < Q` or `Q > P`.

Third, check if the graph contains cycles. The inequalities are satisfiable iff the graph contains no cycles.

You might want to google for 2-SAT, which is related to this problem.

Comment: Requires a least element.

Comment: @AlecTeal care to elaborate?

Comment: Inequalities are an "equivalence relation" The only sets of equalities that make sense are subsets of the ordering you started with. What you've done is a lattice, a lattice is a partial ordering if it has no cycles. Power sets define a lattice, but are not an ordering, they are partial orderings. Maths ftw! :P

Comment: Additionally, an ordering can be thought of as a bijection between a set and (a subset of) the natural numbers, then taking the order of the natural numbers on. A bijection is a mapping remember. that bijection is a lot harder to create on a graph. Cycles mean the bijection doesn't exist.... you get the idea.

Comment: Not by themselves, but an ordering is a set where if a>=b and a<=b then a=b. Also cycles => no bijection. But the power-set lattice has no cycles either yet it not an ordering. Contradiction there. Inequalities have a transitive property, a X b and b X c means a X c, but you are right I used the wrong term.

Comment: @Henrik do you not mean replace all occurrences of P with Q instead of the other way round?

Comment: @user2454986 that makes no difference